# NGINX Proxy with a domain, instead of a ip adress

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have a frontend in angular which scrapes from other pages. Because of CORS, I created a proxy server, which also runs on my VPS. If I'm starting Angular in localhost and my proxy on my VPS, I can use my Proxy with the IP address:port of my VPS. That's all good, but I need to use HTTPS, because the whole page is running on HTTPS. Here comes nginx with my domain, which does not work. I set everything up, but it still won't work, seems like I'm having a misconfiguration?

My nginx configuration:

```html
server {
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  root /var/www/docs;

  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
  location /proxy { //HERE COMES MY PASS TO MY PROXY
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
.... SSL CONFIGURATION
```

Probably is the proxy_pass here wrong?

This is my nodejs proxy:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
// Listen on a specific host via the HOST environment variable
var host = process.env.HOST || 'domain.com'; 
// Listen on a specific port via t.he PORT environment variable
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var cors_proxy = require('cors-anywhere');
cors_proxy.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
    requireHeader: ['origin', 'x-requested-with'],
    removeHeaders: ['cookie', 'cookie2']
}).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Running CORS Anywhere on ' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

If I'm trying with '0.0.0.0' instead of my domain name, it works with http://ip:port/target, but it does not work with domain.com/proxy/target. Then I become an "invalid host" error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem myself.
Problem was a missing / behind my proxy_pass
Solution is: "proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;" instead of "proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;"